# getting exception while deploying web app on glassfish server

Tags: hibernate, jpa, glassfish

I am getting below exception

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001301: Annotation @org.glassfish.api.admin.RestEndpoints(value=[@org.glassfish.api.admin.RestEndpoint(path=enable-secure-admin, description=enable-secure-admin, useForAuthorization=false, params=[], opType=POST, configBean=interface com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.Domain)]) is not a qualifier
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-001301: Annotation @org.glassfish.api.admin.RestEndpoints(value=[@org.glassfish.api.admin.RestEndpoint(path=enable-secure-admin, description=enable-secure-admin, useForAuthorization=false, params=[], opType=POST, configBean=interface com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.Domain)]) is not a qualifier
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.checkQualifier(ResolvableBuilder.java:205)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.addQualifier(ResolvableBuilder.java:175)
    at org.jboss.weld.resolution.ResolvableBuilder.addQualifiers(ResolvableBuilder.java:198)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.resolveDecorators(BeanManagerImpl.java:876)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BeanInjectionTarget.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(BeanInjectionTarget.java:122)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetInitializationContext.initialize(InjectionTargetInitializationContext.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.InjectionTargetService.initialize(InjectionTargetService.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:407)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

not getting the reason for exception?

Comment: Please give us less information about what you are trying to do...the reason is probably related to security.

Comment: I got same exception trying to deploy on Glassfish with Eclipse 2019-03 WST + Glassfish Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to pinpoint the exact reason but this line in exception :

> configBean=interface com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.Domain)])
>   is not a qualifier

suggest that in the application a qualifier is being used incorrectly. May be a class import is not correct